# Rotativa Page-Break doesn't work

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

I use wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.4 together with Rotativa MVC (C#). I used `page-break-after: always` to generate a page-break. But somehow it doesn't apply the styles to my generated pdf.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue. It seems that Rotativa doesn't have an answer for this issue.

CSS:

```
.page-breaker {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 120px;
  clear: both;
  page-break-after: always;
  margin-left: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="page-breaker">.....</div>
```

Thx :)

Comment: Do you have any content inside the div?

Comment: @DavidG Yes I use some images aswell as text. 
For example my Titlepage: 

`<div class="page-breaker">
<br /><br />
<div class="blueContainer">
<h1 class="titlepage">
<b>@Resources.General.pdfTitle</b><br />
@Resources.General.pdfSubtitleOutro
</h1>
<br />
</div>
</div>`

Comment: Can you post the whole html page code?

Comment: Have you figured it out and found a solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @DilaraAlbayrak
It worked for me to change the rotativa version 1.6.4 along with Rotativa.MVC v2.0.3 and Rotativa.Core v2.0.0 (as far as I know that works with wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the rotativa and wkhtmltopdf versions to the following:

> Rotativa v1.6.4
>
> Rotativa.MVC v2.0.3
>
> Rotativa.Core v2.0.0

I updated the nuget references in my project. As far as I know Rotativa v1.6.4 works with **wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1**. This version of wkhtmltopdf allows you to do page breaks like so:

```
.page-breaker {
   display: block;
   clear: both;
   page-break-after: always;
}
```

Comment: I've tried several versions for this, and this still ignores any css. In version 1.6.1 locally it does work, but then publishing to IIS 10 on Server2012 R2, there is a incompatible message.

Qt: Untested Windows version 6.2 detected!
Error: Failed loading page https://a.b.co.uk/p/e/2198 (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)